# WCF NetTCPBinding in a Load Balanced Environment; what is the correct configuration?

Tags: c#, wcf, load-balancing, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding

I have been battling to resolve wcf issues on our production servers. One of the errors thrown is "The server rejected the upgrade request." among other weird errors I'm receiving. Our applications runs on the Citrix environment for the front end and our application servers host our WCF Services. We have two application servers set up for load balancing and this KEMP server supports sticky ip's since we are using nettcpbinding. However, I am not sure if we have configured our NetTCP settings correctly as the application frequently uses 100% CPU, when more than 5 users log onto an application. After an iisreset, it takes about an hour for this to re-occur. Please find below the configuration of the NETTcpBinding below:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpLargeBindingEndpoint"
             closeTimeout="00:05:00"
             openTimeout="00:05:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:15:00"
             sendTimeout="00:15:00"
             transactionFlow="false"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             listenBacklog="10"
             portSharingEnabled="false"
            >
      <reliableSession enabled="false"/>
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I have tried searching articles for the correct settings to have for nettcpbindng, but not luck and the most helpful is this msdn article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273122(v=vs.100).aspx
Is there something I'm doing wrong in these settings? Please assist

Comment: Is any of these helpful: http://charliedigital.com/2009/04/17/wcf-load-balancing-an-end-to-end-example-for-nettcpbinding/, 
https://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/wcf-load-balance-tcp-problem-54962.aspx ?

Comment: Hi, Yes I did have a look at that article too, but no luck

Comment: The best sure fire options for diagnosing the problem are going to be perf counters and a memdump.